# LaTeX Special char

Tags: pdftex, symbols

I need to input a special char: a *u* with a small *e* as an accent. In windows I received it as **uͤ** however I am not able to find it not as unicode nor in symbols-a4.pdf file.
Can someone tell me how to input this special char?

Comment: Since you have the symbol you can just copy & paste it into your LaTeX document.

Comment: I am using `pdflatex` with some other packages and somehow is not recognized.

Comment: Yes, pdflatex’s Unicode support is limited. I honestly recommend moving to LuaTeX but otherwise Steven’s or egreg’s solutions are a fairly good workarounds.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The macro `\elaut{}` will work with all LaTeX engines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\elaut[1]{%
  \stackengine{.75pt}{#1}{\tiny e\kern.5pt}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\begin{document}
 Ich bin m\elaut{u}de.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work well. The word is in a footnote but this macro seems to work and there is not issue! thank you!

Answer (score 12):

[image]

with lualatex or xelatex (using any font that has the e accent)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}

uͤ
\end{document}
```

It is not a single Unicode character but the pair

```
U+0075 LATIN SMALL LETTER U 
U+0364 COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER E
```

Answer (score 11):

With pdflatex you can use something like the following:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\e}{} % initialize
\DeclareRobustCommand{\e}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \check@mathfonts
  \vbox{\ialign{%
    \hfil##\hfil\cr
    \kern5\fontdimen1\font
    \fontsize{\fpeval{\ssf@size/1.5}}{0}\selectfont e\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\vspace{\fpeval{\ssf@size/8}pt}}
    #1\cr
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

X\e{a}\e{o}\e{u}Y

\textit{X\e{a}\e{o}\e{u}Y}

\textbf{X\e{a}\e{o}\e{u}Y}

\textit{\textbf{X\e{a}\e{o}\e{u}Y}}

\medskip

{\Large X\e{a}\e{o}\e{u}Y}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that destroys copyability of text out of the rendered document.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That's difficult (read impossible) to avoid with `pdflatex`

Comment: Ah, I had misses that this was specifically for pdflatex. In LuaTeX and XeLaTeX this “just works”.

Comment: unfortunately is too much for me in `pdflatex`. but It is good to be listed here maybe someone else could use this solution.